# Why are unittest2 methods camelCase if names_with_underscores are preferred?

Tags: python, pep8, unittest2

Here's the section of PEP8 that describes how function names should be:

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
>   underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style

Why didn't they change the function names? This is especially relevant for Python 3 where backwards compatibility was not maintained.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [unittest2 website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2):

> unittest2 is a backport of the new features added to the unittest
>   testing framework in Python 2.7. It is tested to run on Python 2.4 -
>   2.7.
>
> To use unittest2 instead of unittest simply replace import unittest
>   with import unittest2.

Its a bit confusing as from a version 2 is not expected to be a backport, but a new major release with (probably) new features. Anyway, the main idea is creating a backport where all the user has to do is changing the import statement. For this they could not change their method signatures

Also, from [unittest website](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html):

> The Python unit testing framework, sometimes referred to as “PyUnit,”
>   is a Python language version of JUnit, by Kent Beck and Erich Gamma.
>   JUnit is, in turn, a Java version of Kent’s Smalltalk testing
>   framework. Each is the de facto standard unit testing framework for
>   its respective language.

So this explains the whole resemblance between the frameworks and *probably* the camel case notation